# What was the Chinese impact on Japanese culture and the arts after ~1750?

Tags: japan, china, cultural-history, modern

What significant and subtle impacts has China had on Japanese social dynamics and the arts from ~1750 to the early nineteen hundreds?

If at all possible include dates on which changes happened abruptly or when the effects of gradual influence becomes apparent.

Comment: Should it worth mentioning that there were no translation of the famous chinese novel "Hónglóumèng" into Japanese until 1920, because the japans actually prefer to read it in Chinese?

Comment: what's the significance of the date 1750? it's not the beginning of any significant historical period in China or Japan. The Meiji restoration didn't happen until a hundred years later.